# Profiles linked to a top level profile

Tags: getstream-io

I'm starting with stream.io. My architecture needs to allow profiles within profiles. This can go with 1 level for now.  What I would like to achieve is when a user follows a top level profile, that user also follows the profiles contained.  Would this be possible with the API and services?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: @StefanBecker sure will do! as soon as I get through the research, i've only started to investigate on it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if by profile you mean feed, then you can simply call follow_many to have the user follow all the feeds within that higher level feed (or profile). Is that what you're looking to do?